# If radio button is checked, display a text box in Java

Tags: java, android-studio, radio-button

I am trying to create a quiz like app. Basically, the user selects their options and it displays the results at the end (in the form of recommendations on where to travel to next for example). So if two specific radio buttons are checked, then how can I display a text box in which I can provide recommendations in the form of text? I would really appreciate it if someone could guide me in the right direction. Thank you.

Again, I have found many answers in JS or Jquery but none in Java which is why I had to ask. I am using Android Studio.

EDIT:(this is my code, but I am unsure of how to fix these errors (the errors are view, getId, and setText)
`public class MainActivity4 extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private String view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);

    public void onClick(View view) {
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_mountains);
        RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_sights_and_landmarks);
        RadioButton rb3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_water_bodies);
        RadioButton rb4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_water_sports);
        RadioButton rb5 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_islands);
        RadioButton rb6 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_hiking);
        RadioButton rb7 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_road_trips);
        RadioButton rb8 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_beaches);
        RadioButton rb9 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_city_travel);
        RadioButton rb10 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_deserts);
        RadioButton rb11 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_wildlife_viewing);
        RadioButton rb12 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_glaciers);
        RadioButton rb13 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_coasts);

        switch(((RadioButton) view).findViewById()) {
            case R.id.radio_mountains:
            case R.id.radio_sights_and_landmarks:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_mountains:
            case R.id.radio_water_sports:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_mountains:
            case R.id.radio_hiking:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_mountains:
            case R.id.radio_road_trips:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_mountains:
            case R.id.radio_beaches:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_mountains:
            case R.id.radio_city_travel:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_mountains:
            case R.id.radio_wildlife_viewing:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_water_bodies:
            case R.id.radio_sights_and_landmarks:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_water_bodies:
            case R.id.radio_water_sports:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_water_bodies:
            case R.id.radio_hiking:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_water_bodies:
            case R.id.radio_road_trips:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_water_bodies:
            case R.id.radio_beaches:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_water_bodies:
            case R.id.radio_city_travel:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_islands:
            case R.id.radio_sights_and_landmarks:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_islands:
            case R.id.radio_water_sports:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_islands:
            case R.id.radio_hiking:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_islands:
            case R.id.radio_road_trips:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_islands:
            case R.id.radio_beaches:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_islands:
            case R.id.radio_city_travel:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_islands:
            case R.id.radio_wildlife_viewing:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_glaciers:
            case R.id.radio_sights_and_landmarks:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_glaciers:
            case R.id.radio_water_sports:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_glaciers:
            case R.id.radio_hiking:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_glaciers:
            case R.id.radio_road_trips:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_glaciers:
            case R.id.radio_beaches:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_glaciers:
            case R.id.radio_city_travel:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_glaciers:
            case R.id.radio_wildlife_viewing:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_deserts:
            case R.id.radio_sights_and_landmarks:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_deserts:
            case R.id.radio_water_sports:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_deserts:
            case R.id.radio_hiking:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_deserts:
            case R.id.radio_road_trips:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_deserts:
            case R.id.radio_beaches:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_deserts:
            case R.id.radio_city_travel:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_deserts:
            case R.id.radio_wildlife_viewing:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_coasts:
            case R.id.radio_sights_and_landmarks:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_coasts:
            case R.id.radio_water_sports:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_coasts:
            case R.id.radio_hiking:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_coasts:
            case R.id.radio_road_trips:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_coasts:
            case R.id.radio_beaches:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_coasts:
            case R.id.radio_city_travel:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;
            case R.id.radio_coasts:
            case R.id.radio_wildlife_viewing:
                if (checked)
                    findViewById(R.id.textView4).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
                break;

        }
    }

    {
        }

    }}`
```

Comment: Please include a code example of what you have tried into your question. Thanks.

Comment: Sure I have edited the questions with the errors. The errors are setText, getId, and View view. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of your experience level with android studio, so I'm going to assume you know how to use `OnClickListener`s. If not, check out this tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=01gOTzT2v-0

Rather than creating a TextView on a click, try having an empty TextView, and then simply change the text inside. Try using this method for your onClick:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            if (checked)
        findViewById(R.id.textView).setText("Button1 has been chosen");
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            if (checked)
        findViewById(R.id.textView).setText("Button2 has been chosen");
            break;
    }
}
```

You'll have to change the "R.id.*something*" to the appropriate ids. I trust you'll be able to use the method, or use the useful parts. Hope I helped!

Comment: Thank you so much, definitely helped! I appreciate your time.

Comment: Hi, if you are still available, I keep getting an error in setText, so do I have to import anything or is there any other way to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Make sure that your parameter is a string. Unlike `println()` and similar methods, `setText()` only accepts strings. Try importing `import android.widget.TextView;`. Aside from that, I'd need more information.

Answer (score -1):

```
TextView textView; 

public void onCreate(){
    textView = findViewById(R.id.paymentMethodTextView);
}
//Out of onCreate
@SuppressLint({"NonConstantResourceId", "SetTextI18n"})
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.cashPayment:
            if (checked)
                textView.setText("Button1 has been chosen");
            break;
        case R.id.cardPayment:
            if (checked)
                textView.setText("Button2 has been chosen");
            break;
    }
}
```